# Removing a node from a linked-list

Tags: c++, linked-list, hashtable, nodes

I've created a Hash-table and I want to remove a node from the linked-list. The code works for removing the first node but not for removing others.

```
void intHashTable::remove(int num){
int location = ((unsigned)num) % size;
Node * runner = table[location];
int checker;

if(runner->next == NULL){
    if(num == table[location]->num){
        table[location] = NULL;
    }
}else{
    if(table[location]->num == num){
        table[location] = table[location]->next;
    }else{
        //This part doesn't seem to be working.
        Node *temp = runner->next;
        while(temp != NULL){ 
            if(temp->num == num){
                runner->next = temp->next;
                delete(temp);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: But what have you tried already? What have you found out? Please show some effort when demanding unpaid support.

Comment: @phresnel I'm not demanding unpaid support. My code is there - that is my effort.

Comment: So, what have you tried already? What have you found out? "It does not work" shows no problem-effort at all. Does it not compile? Does it crash with an exception? Do you have an infinite loop? Do you go out of memory? What does the debugger say? Just to name some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't updated `temp` to point to the next item within the loop:

```
temp = temp->next;
```

You also appear to represent an empty row with a `NULL` pointer in your table, but you don't handle this case properly in your code - if `runner` is `NULL` then you'll crash when you try to access `runner->next` in the first check. Also, you're failing to delete the node in some cases.

To fix these issues, you can update your code to something like this:

```
void intHashTable::remove(int num)
{
    int location = ((unsigned)num) % size;
    Node * runner = table[location];

    if (runner != NULL) {
        if (runner->num == num) {
            delete runner;
            table[location] = NULL;
        } else {
            while (runner->next != NULL) {
                if (runner->next->num == num) {
                    Node *temp = runner->next;
                    runner->next = runner->next->next;
                    delete temp;
                    break;
                }
                runner = runner->next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that I've removed the brackets from `delete`, which is a C++ keyword and not a function.

If you use doubly-linked lists (i.e. with a previous pointer as well as a next) then you can simplify this code a little, although for something like a hash table where you only tend to iterate through in one direction it's probably not worth the expense of the extra pointer (an extra 8 bytes per item on a 64-bit system).

Comment: He breaks out of the loop after deletion.

Comment: And also `runner = temp` before your line. Though normally instead of peaking ahead with `temp`, I see this written to remember a `prev` (but it should work either way).

Comment: This wouldn't work. Current pointer update must be done outside `if`

Comment: I'm pretty sure these comments were for the previous version of my answer which, to be fair, was too concise to be clear. I've edited it to show a rewritten function which fixes several issues.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't updated `temp` and `runner` variables inside loop:

```
    while(temp != NULL)
    { 
        if(temp->num == num)
        {
            runner->next = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            break;
        }
        runner = temp;     // Keep previous element to change its next pointer when num found
        temp = temp->next; // Advance current pointer to next element
    }
```